# Числовой первичный ключ vs текстового первичного ключа

Tags: база-данных

Всех с наступающими майскими праздниками! Возможно, тема избитая, хотя я не нашел все же явных указаний в базовых мануалах к СУБД и книгах по БД. Хотел спросить, что будет более правильным, если первичный ключ будет числовым значением и соответственно иметь индекс PK или же же первичный ключ текстового поля, тоже уникального значения? Это про целесообразность и производительность работы с такой таблицей. Почему-то склоняюсь все же к первому, что числовой инкремент более правильный для таблицы имеющей справочную информацию, допустим, номера автомобилей. Использую СУБД Postgres. Хотел бы знать как для этой субд, так и для других СУБД преимущества и минусы в использовании первичным ключом числового значения или текстового поля.

Comment: Серьезной разницы нет. Однако я голосую за простой численный айдишник просто потому, что если в системе возникнет таблица с произвольными ссылками на записи (т.е. из любых таблиц), то гораздо проще будет ссылаться на обычный айдишник, и потому что будет сохраняться история добавления хоть в каком-то, пусть и не обязательно очень точном, виде. Что до производительности, то у инкрементального идентификатора она скорее всего чуть выше, чем у строки, но требования приложения здесь должны цениться выше этого минимального выигрыша.

Comment: Etki, да это я и хотел услышать. А если говорить об индексировании такого поля, то индексирование числового поля тоже будет существенно быстрее работать, чем индекс тестового поля. Не так ли? Подчеркну текстового поля, а не строкового. А это разница большая. В данный момент используется citext - это специальный тип данных для хранения текста, игнорируя регистр и особенности кодировок.

Comment: индекс по-хорошему должен храниться в оперативке, так что разница хоть и будет, скорее всего окажется незаметной даже на больших данных. На практике не проверял, но при достаточном желании можно набить базу данных миллионом-другим рандомных записей и оценить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первичный ключ в БД - это, как правило, то значение, которое используется для ссылок на записи в этой таблице. Поэтому, если такие ссылки в принципе предусмотрены, первичный ключ желательно держать как можно меньшего размера.

В принципе, написанного выше достаточно чтобы во всех таблицах-справочниках сделать первичные ключи числовыми. Но если все же по какой-то причине приходится делать первичный ключ строковым - то ни в коем случае не следует делать его кластерным индексом, если только он не является единственным индексом в таблице.

Разумеется, я говорю про длинные строки. Если строка занимает меньше места, чем "обычное" число - проблем с ней не должно возникнуть.

Comment: Можете привести аргументацию почему строковый PK не надо делать кластерным?

Comment: Потому что кластерный индекс, ускоряя один из запросов (выборку по своему ключу), замедляет все остальные. Наличие же других индексов кроме кластерного подразумевает, что запросы к этой таблице будут идти разные. Поэтому скорость работы кластерного индекса критически важна. А индексы по строковым полям обладают довольно малым коэффициентом разветвления, по сравнению с индексами по числовым полям, что замедляет их работу.

Comment: О каком разветвлении идёт речь если кластерный индекс по определению это успорядоченная последовательность (позволяющая делать бинарный поиск)? Также я не понял что вы имели в виду под "замедляет все остальные".

Comment: Кластерный индекс - это такое же B+-tree, как и остальные индексы. А замедление заключается в следующем. Чтобы найти запись по некоторому индексу в таблице без кластерного индекса, надо сначала найти в индексе номер ее строки, после чего найти в таблице саму запись по номеру.

При наличии же кластерного индекса, надо сначала найти в индексе ее кластерный ключ, а потом выполнить поиск по кластерному индексу. Большая длина кластерного ключа увеличивает стоимость обеих операций поиска, за счет увеличения высоты дерева.

Comment: Вы заблуждаетесь. Кластерный индекс сортирует таблицу физически по `PK`. Соответственно остальные ваши рассуждения тоже оторваны от реальности. Извините.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177443.aspx Цитирую: "В SQL Server индексы организованы в виде сбалансированных деревьев. Каждая страница в сбалансированном дереве индекса называется узлом индекса. Верхний узел сбалансированного дерева называется корневым. Узлы нижнего уровня индекса называются конечными. Все уровни индекса между корневыми и конечными узлами называются промежуточными. В кластеризованном индексе конечные узлы содержат страницы данных базовой таблицы."

Comment: Конечно, это только одна из СУБД, но такой выбор представления кластерного индекса не случаен. Включите голову: если хранить записи в виде упорядоченного списка, как это предлагаете делать вы, то сколько времени займет вставка элемента в середину этого списка?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23307/discussion-between-pavel-mayorov-and-petr-abdulin).

Comment: Это важная деталь реализации (фактически они реализуют бинарный поиск в виде уже готовых данных индекса), не отменяющие факта физической сортировки записей в таблице (это написано даже по приведённой вами ссылке). И да, вставка в таблицу с кластерным индексом очень дорогая, именно поэтому кластерный PK это почти всегда автоинкремент (вставка в конец таблицы).

Comment: Вот вы и ответили самому себе, почему строковый индекс не должен быть кластерным - ведь на нем нельзя сделать автоинкремент! :)

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае быстрее будет тот, что меньше по размеру, т.е. числовой практически всегда.

Преимущество в использовании текста может быть если "кто-то" делает очень много `WHERE` по этому полю, но при этом этот "кто-то" не знает внутрениих `Id`. Такие ситуации бывают довольно редко, т.к. обычно для выбора значения предварительно предоставляется справочник вида `{Id: Name}`, т.е. `Id` доступно клиенту.